# knitr showing R Chunk Code output after whole block of R Chunk Code

Tags: r, latex, knitr, sweave

I wonder how to show the R Chunk Code output after whole block of R Chunk Code not the output after each code line.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document}

<< Test >>=
1:10
args(lm)
@ 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you writing in Rmarkdown ?? If so, there is an option you can add in R chunk like

````
```{r,results = "hold"}

your R code

```
````

Otherwise you should figure out how to give this argument to knitr while converting.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like those chunks come from Sweave.

I would suggest to first present only code, and then to present only results. This means you would have to double your chunks, but a copy of every chunk would have to have a different chunk option. Like this:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document}
```

here are chunks that will generate only code

```
<< Test1, results='hide' >>=
1:10
args(lm)
@
<< Test2, results='hide' >>=
2:5
args(lm)
@
```

and here are chunks that will generate only results

```
<< Test3, echo=FALSE >>=
1:10
args(lm)
@
<< Test4, echo=FALSE >>=
2:5
args(lm)
@ 
\end{document}
```

I wish I didn't make mistake with those chunk options name, cose Im rather familiar with knitr insead od sweave.

If you want to learn knitr visit webiste of this [RNINJA](http://yihui.name/knitr/)